# VS Code Cannot Resolve node modules

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I have a node project inside another node project. When I open the root project in VS Code, node modules give me the error `Cannot find module or its corresponding type declarations.`. But if I open the child node project I don't get this error anymore. Any help regarding this?

[Package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/010L2.png)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WoaFr.png)

Didn't find any leads so far. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: welcome! please provide _exact_ steps to reproduce the setup (a [mre]). Then I'll take a look :)

Answer (score 0):

Open your first project in first folder. Open your second project in its *inside folder*.

Or merge their files and make them one project.

There is a reason why they are in seperated folder. smh.